# Can't record audio on VLC (High Sierra)

Tags: audio, high-sierra, microphone, vlc

I'm running VLC 3.0.3 on High Sierra and I'm trying to record video+audio. The video part seems to work just fine, but I get an error for the audio every time I try to record. The error reads:

````
Your input can't be opened
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'qtsound://0c-e0-e4-f7-c4-bb:input'. Check the log for details.```
````

Unfortunately, after extensive search I wasn't able to find the log location for VLC, but I ran it from the command line using `-v`, `-vv` and `-vvv`  and unfortunately I can't get an error or debug message that explains the problem further.

I tried both with the built-in microphone and a headset.
QuickTime can record audio with no problem.

Comment: Try contacting VLC directly for support.